# Does this proof (Lie-Kolchin) suffer from a loss of injectivity?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

In the following proof (after "But there is a more elementary proof"), I was confused on something.

[image]

Apparently we can assume without loss of generality that $V = V_{\chi}$.  In this case, here is what I think Springer is saying: let $H = (G,G)$, and assume $G$ is acting as a group of automorphisms on $V$.  Every $x \in H$, interpreted as a linear operator on $V$, has determinant one.  At the same time, $x.v = \chi(x)v$ for all $x \in H$.  Thus the matrix of transformation of any $x \in H$ is $$\begin{pmatrix} \chi(x) & & 0 \\  & \ddots & \\ 0& &  \chi(x) \end{pmatrix}$$ with $\chi(x)^n = 1$.  Thus $H$ is finite, because there are only finitely many such matrices (actually now that I think about it, I don't see why that's true either; $\chi$ could be the trivial character)).

My issue with this proof is that in the argument above, we have *injected* $H$ into a group of matrices, and showed that that group was finite.  On the other hand, if we don't assume that $V = V_{\chi}$, then we would be taking elements of $x \in G$, interpreting those elements as automorphisms of $V$, and then restricting those automorphisms to the $G$-stable subspace $V_{\chi}$.  In that case, the image of $H$ is finite, as Springer argued.  How does that mean that $H$ itself is finite?  We do not even know that $V$ is the direct sum of the $V_{\chi}$.

Comment: $G$ is assumed to be a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n$, i.e. the representation is faithful.

Comment: Don't you lose faithfulness if you replace $V$ by one of the $V_{\chi}$?

Comment: He also meant to replace $G$ by its image in $\mathrm{GL}_{V_\chi}$. Or if you don't want to do that you can argue as follow: the image of $(G,G)$ in $\mathrm{GL}_{V_\chi}$ is connected and finite, so it is trivial. Hence the image of $G$ in $\mathrm{GL}_{V_\chi}$ is commutative.